# What visa do my wife and children need to travel to the UK with me?

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel, family

I am from Mumbai, India. I will soon go on a short trip to the UK on a 6m business visa. Am planning to take my wife and two kids (7 years and 2 years) along for some sightseeing over the weekends. My wife cannot speak fluent English as she has studied in vernacular medium.
What visa will be required for her and my kids? Will it be dependent on my visa or independent?
Also, does it matter in the Visa application if she is not good at English? Just to add, we will be there for 2-3 weeks.

Comment: @pnuts the question is the same, so Gayot should just update his answer.